# How to use template to make variables generalized in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to take input from the user and the user have multiple choice to enter the different types of inputs(char, int float). And according to the value entered I have to take proper action.

eg. I have a function below :-

```
int* function(int data)
{
    int a[50];
    int k = 0;
    a[k] = data;
    k++;
    // I want to make choice generalized so that it can accept both type of
    // values int as well as char.
    cout<<"\n Enter integer element to insert into array, otherwise press 'n' to terminate array list: ";
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice != 'n')
        function(choice);
    return a;
}
```

So, in the above example I want to make choice generalized. I how to use template for function and classes but, I want to do this for variable. Please help.

NOTE: the above code is just a example to illustrate my problem.

Thank's.

Comment: You mean you want `int` to be some template parameter?

Comment: Read the data in as a `std::string` and then parse it to figure out what it is.

Comment: @TartanLlama, if the choice has int data type then I want to store it into array and if the choice is 'n' then i want to terminate storing elements into list

Comment: @NathanOliver , okay you mean I will take choice as string ans then after parsing I will see whether the user that entered a int or a char and according to that I will perform the task? Okay , this is one way of doing it but can I use template to make the `variable 'choice'` generalized?

Comment: No.  Templates have to be known at compile time.  If you do not know what the user is going to enter then one of the standard methods to get the input is to read it in as a string since it can hold anything and then parse it to figure out what the user actually entered.

Comment: Your question aside, have you tried to run this? You are heading straight into undefined behavior territory.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think I can also use a class, structures to make `choice variable` generalized . right?

Comment: @StoryTeller , no actually this is just a example that I gave. Actually I have a linked list program which I was trying to make more user friendly. So I thought to ask my problem with a example rather than pasting few hundreds lines of code

Comment: This is SO, If you post erroneous code in examples, it'll draw the discussion away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are a compile time construct, so there is no way to let the user input have an influence on the template type.

What you can do is some template based automation of the input conversion where you decide which template instantiations should be checked. Suppose you have a class to handle your input conversion called `GenericInput` with template functions `bool GenericInput::CanConvert<TargetType>()` and `TargetType GenericInput::Convert<TargetType>()`

```
GenericInput in;
std::cin >> in;
if (in.CanConvert<int>()) {
    // some action
}
else if (in.CanConvert<char>()) {
    // another action
}
// ...
```

It would basically be a wrapper for the idea to first read the string and then check, how the string can be interpreted.

To implement it, you would need the following things:

Overload `operator >>`

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& stream, GenericInput& element) {
    /* TODO: read input into string member of GenericInput object */
    return stream;
}
```

The `GenericInput` class

```
class GenericInput {
private:
    std::string _inputElement; // store input as base for conversion
public:
    // TODO: standard class implementation

    template <typename TargetType>
    bool CanConvert() {
        // TODO: create std::stringstream from _inputElement and try to read into a TargetType variable
        // return true if the stringstream is valid after the read
    }

    template <typename TargetType>
    TargetType Convert() {
        // TODO: create std::stringstream from _inputElement and try to read into a TargetType variable
        // return variable if the stringstream is valid after the read, otherwise report error
    }
}
```

Regarding the "valid" stringstream after read, it might be important to check two things: if the stringstream is in some kind of error state, conversion failed. If there are unread characters in the stringstream, the conversion was incomplete, which may also count as a failure.

Please don't expect this to be working out of the box, its more of an idea scratch than an actual implementation.